# Compatibility issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, compatibility

I am building a newbie website.

When I test/inspect it with **ms-edge 91.0.864.67 X64**, I am getting a compatibility issue:

```
> 'content-type' header charset value should be 'utf-8'. Affected
> resources "Content-Type: text/css"
```

I read and tried to put `@charset "UTF-8";` on the top of each CSS (even bootstrap) with no success. When I do the same test/inspect in chrome or firefox there is no error.

Could you please explain what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: The `Content-Type` header is present in the HTTP response from the server responding with the CSS. It needs to be configured at the web server level.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on what I could gather from your question, it looks like the browser is not able to detect your `charset` meta tag in your HTML, which is then causing problems with your CSS.

Here is the boilerplate I always use. Maybe try pasting it in to see if the problem was a typo or similar small issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Additionally please check out the [Stack Overflow Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [Minimum Reproducible Example outline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you, but the same result.

Answer (score -1):

The best that I can say is try a different browser.

Comment: <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.5.0.2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">

</head>

Comment: If you don't know the answer, it's better not to answer than to just keep throwing out half-formed guesses, in my opinion. Especially since the meta tags you put in your answer have nothing to do with charset or Content-type.

Comment: I removed `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` because edge saying "The 'x-ua-compatible' meta element should not be specified as it is not needed."

Comment: I'm not sure. There is nothing wrong with this code. My best answer would be try a different browser.

Comment: @MarejKorany I was talking about the answer, not the question. And Stack Overflow is not like other sites, it has quality standards and rules enforcing those standards. Please take the [tour] and read the [help/on-topic] about what's on topic and [ask]. For the answer, there is [answer].

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry, but I still need any answer :)

Comment: @MarejKorany It would be easier to find you an answer if you gave more information about what kind of web server you are running, because as my comment on your question notes, *that's* where you have to configure it.

Comment: I am using Wampserver64, but I think the problem is not from the server because other browsers are not showing the same issue.